# Call Android Intent.ACTION_INSERT from Chrome web page

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, android-contacts

[It's possible to invoke Android intents from Chrome web page](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

Is it possible to invoke the [Contacts ACTION_INSERT Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Contacts) ? If so , can someone provide an example for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no. You can send Intent from Chrome to apps. See this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents), it's easy. No, the app that receives the intent must be properly configured to handle the intent, and I believe that the contact app cannot handle the 'add' contact intent.